# Foreach within a foreach with if else inside lists everything twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, foreach

I dont understand what am i missing here? in my view my code lists each group twice??

```
 <% foreach (var group in Model.AllGroups)  //53 entries here
 { %>     
   <% foreach (var groupForUser in Model.GroupsForUser) //2 entries here
      { %>    
      <% if (group.GroupId == groupForUser.GroupId) 
         { %>
           <div id="Div1" style="width:auto; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px; **background-color:green**;" >
             <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: groupForUser.GroupId %>)" id="changer1<%: group.GroupId %>"><%: groupForUser.Name %></a></h3> 
           </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="Hidden1" name="group<%: group.GroupId %>" value="" />
       <% }
          else %>  
       <% { %>
           <div id="group-select<%: group.GroupId %>" style="width:auto; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px;" >
             <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: group.GroupId %>)" id="changer<%: group.GroupId %>"><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
           </div>
           <input type="hidden" id="group<%: group.GroupId %>" name="group<%: group.GroupId %>" value="" />
       <% } } }%>
```

is there a better way of doing this? and also why are the groups listed twice in my view?
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through the inner foreach and if check?

Comment: if what i have in Model.GroupsForUser matches any of what I have in Model.AllGroups i want the background-color to be green to show that  Model.GroupsForUser are pre-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're listed twice because you have 2 entries within `GroupsForUsers` and you are outputting **every** group on each iteration (because of your `else` statement in the inner `foreach`).

A better way would be to cut out the inner loop completely (using Linq), something like:

```
<% foreach (var group in Model.AllGroups)
   { %>      
     <% if (Model.GroupsForUsers.Any(g => g.GroupId == group.GroupId)
        { %>
            //make it green
     <% }
        else %>  
     <% { %>
           //make it red
   <% } }%>
```

Comment: aaah yes knew there was something not right with my code, thanks!